# Implementing LinkedList in java

Tags: java, data-structures

I needed to implement LinkedList without using collections.What are the java concepts which needed to be known before implementing it.

Please suggest the best place to learn for it.

Comment: Arrays (not sure if they qualify as collection) - Objects - Referencing objects. Btw: this question is too broad for SO.

Comment: @luk2302 i need to implement LinkedList,Double LinkedList and so on .I wanted to program Data Structures using Java.I  am not aware of how to do it.Please suggest

Comment: No, using google is one very first and most important skills you need to master in the beginning - and this is the first lesson: google for "java linkedlist implementation". Literally the first hit on google is everything you need.

Comment: @luk2302 i googled it and somesuggest we need to know about Generics and others suggest that we  need to know about Externalizable.I am not aware of which to use

Answer (score 1):

Javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Quick tutorials:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedlist_class.htm
- http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/linkedlist-in-java-with-example/

Carnegie Mellon University posted a useful source to their website detailing implementation from scratch: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/code/LinkedList.java

Do a quick Google search and read up on the official documentation next time before posting such a fundamental question to Stack Overflow. The best use of the forum is to post debugging questions or spawn further intelligent debate on algorithms and other coding procedures.

Comment: I needed to implement LinkedList from Scratch without using the Collections Framework.

Comment: @Yuvaraj see my updated response